# How do I display on the frontend the result of a method in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-forms

I had the following code inside my `.component.html` file:

```
<div class="someContainer">
       <div class="text--bold">DDisplay this please:</div>
       <div>{{ myObject.date ? '2 Jun' : 'Now' }}</div>
 </div>
```

This worked fina and displayed the date correctly. However I dont want to diplay the hardcoded value '2nd June' I want to display the result of a method:

```
 <div>{{ myObject.date ? myObject.findDate(someParam) | date:'d LLL' : 'Now' }}</div>
```

However, this line does not compile. It says : Expected.

Comment: so you want either `date:'d LLL'` or  `date:'now'` depending on  `myObject.findDate(someParam)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have syntax error, try it like this -

```
 <div>{{ myObject.date ? (myObject.findDate(someParam) | date:'d LLL' : 'Now') : '' }}</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think it should be like this: ` <div>{{ myObject.date ? (myObject.findDate(someParam) | date:'d LLL') : 'Now' }}</div>`  ?

Comment: Ohh, you want to write in that way, I misunderstood

Answer (score 1):

I guessing you want to use `date:'d LLL'` or `date:'now'` depending on the result of `myObject.findDate(someParam)`. Is that correct?

If this is what you are looking for, a solution to your problem would be

```
<div>{{ myObject.date | date: (myObject.findDate(someParam) ? 'd LLL' : 'Now' }}</div>
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/date-pipe-example-uzufzs?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)